# Cronjob is running every hour but not at a specific time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, cron

I have a cronjob on my server that suppose to run a rake script on my rails app everyday at specific time (eg. 8.00 am). I use whenever gem to automate this. This is how it appears currently on the cron file:

```
0 8 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/deploy/apps/myapp/releases/20160121092339 && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake overdue_payments --silent >> /home/deploy/apps/myapp/releases/20160121092339/log/cron.log 2>&1'
```

And it's not working. But strangely enough, if I edit my cron to run for every hour, it is working just fine! Here is how I did it to make it run for every hour:

```
0 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/deploy/apps/myapp/releases/20160121092339 && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake overdue_payments --silent >> /home/deploy/apps/myapp/releases/20160121092339/log/cron.log 2>&1'
```

I have modified my timezone to the local timezone (UK) but still not working:

[image]

Comment: lol at the red crossing out!

Answer (score 1):

We need to specify the timezone to cronjob description. Here is my example:

```
test_cron_job:
  cron: "45 11 * * * Asia/Bangkok"
  class: "Schedulers::TestCronJob"
  queue: default
```

Above cronjob will be run at 11:45 am in Bangkok time. Btw you may find out your timezone by using:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map.values.map(&:tzinfo).map(&:identifier)
```

Comment: Hey man, so in my case should I write it like this?: 0 8 * * * Europe/London /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/deploy/apps/myapp/releases/20160121092339 && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake overdue_payments --silent >> /home/deploy/apps/myapp/releases/20160121092339/log/cron.log 2>&1'

Comment: `0 8 * * * Europe/London` is correct, let try it with a testing cronjob

Comment: Ok great let me know! Because i tried it and it didn't work :(

Comment: Yeah I sure did..and it doesn't matter what time I entered, it still didn't work..

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it! For the timezone, i just need to add TZ before it. So for my case it will be: TZ="Europe/London".

```
0 8 * * * TZ="Europe/London" /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/deploy/apps/myapp/releases/20160121092339 && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake overdue_payments --silent >> /home/deploy/apps/myapp/releases/20160121092339/log/cron.log 2>&1'
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this solution help you

```
every :day, :at => (6..8).to_a.map { |x| ["#{x}:00","#{x}:30", "#{x+1}:00"] }.flatten do
# Run rake task.
end

# => ["6:00", "6:30", "7:00", "7:00", "7:30", "8:00", "8:00", "8:30", "9:00"]
```

Adjust initial range and the inner block to cover any range. Its support 24hr clock.